# msbuild pack command includes directory structure

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-2.0, octopus-deploy

I'm using dotnet core 2.0, building in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).  I added the built-in Visual Studio Build step and am using msbuild with the following arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true  
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"  
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MyProject.BuildVersion.zip"
```

This would build a zip file, but the internal structure was ugly and included the entire artifact staging directory as subfolders.  E.g., the path inside my zip file until I got to the actual website file structure was `Content\d_C\a\1\s\src\MyProjectName\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\PubTmp\Out`

Is there a way to zip up just the project files and have those in the root of the zip file?  I have a workaround using a few extra steps, but it would be nice to be able to use a single build step that also zips everything.

**Edit**

We use Octopus Deploy for deploying to Azure.

Comment: Why does the structure matter? WebDeploy will handle deployment for you.

Comment: @DanielMann - we use Octopus Deploy and I'm using the `Deploy an Azure Web App` step.  The files made it into Azure as-is (but unzipped, as expected).  If there's a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a dotnet core 2.0 project, you can publish project through .NET Core task:

[image]

For Visual Studio Build task, you can try to specify `/P:PackageTempRootDir=""` argument, it will remove source path.

On the other hand, with Azure App Service deploy, the folder structure won’t be remained after deploying to the azure, you can check the folder and files by accessing `https://[app name].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

Comment: We have a QA team that needs to be able to deploy the feature branch they want to test.  Is that available with Azure App Service deployments?  It seemed like that was set up to only deploy when a commit is made to a branch.  But thank you for the other answers.  I did end up using the .NET Core publish task-- that was the alternative I was using.  I'm using the version 2 preview.

Comment: I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: I think it's relevant to this question, since your answer mentions Azure App Service deployments, and I mentioned using a tool (Octopus Deploy) that allows us to queue up deployments without making new commits.  A simple yes or no (at this time, obviously new features are continually being added) would be appreciated!

Comment: @ps2goat There are many questions/issues related to Azure App Service deployments, we can't answer them together in a thread, the forum readers can't recognize questions and answers easily. Regarding this issue, I am not clear about the detail workflow of your requirement with the simple comment, for example, the Azure App Service deployment is the task that to deploy app to azure, it isn't related to the branch. If you mean the build source, you can change the branch when queue build manually. For CI build, it uses the current branch that changed and trigger the build.